# Validatorless Bootstraps in chef 12.2.0

Tags: chef-infra, knife

With chef 12.2.0 , when I try to bootstrap a node , I see following message:

Doing old-style registration with the validation key at /home/xxx/.chef/xxx-validator.pem... Delete your validation key in order to use your user credentials instead. This points out clearly that now validator.pem is used on the target node for registration.

Before chef 12 , the flow was to make sure that the validation.pem is present over the target node. The first chef-client run on the node used to authenticate with the chef-server using validation.pem and later generate a client.pem . Once the client.pem gets generated all the following chef-client run used client.pem instead of validation.pem to authenticate with server.

However now in 12 since validation.pem is not used at all , and may be the user.pem is used , how could one register the node manually , without using bootstrap command ?

Do I need to copy the user.pem to taget node and create client.rb specifying the details ? Can someone please outline the process to register node with chef-server-12 without using knife bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options to register a node on a chef-server:

1. Use knife bootstrap
2. From chef-client first run

For the 1. knife no longer need to copy the validation key, instead it creates the node object and the client key on the chef server and move the private client key to the node, so the registration is already done.

For the 2. you still use the validation.pem file, (when you provision node from a template machine for example) and the chef-client register itself at its first run.

The change on knife bootstrap is to mitigate the need of having the validation.pem file on each admin workstation.

So for your question, the method with chef 12 is still the same if you're not using knife bootstrap.

Comment: @Tensibal Do you have examples of the chef-client commands to run in this case?

Comment: @emeraldjava if you have a question, take some time to write a question in SO and feel free to ping in its comments. Actually I can't tell what point you're asking about here and clearing it out in comments will turn into a mess.